# Image Upload to S3 using CKEditor

Tags: javascript, laravel, amazon-s3, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am able to drag and drop images to a CKEditor text area and upload the images to an S3 bucket. However, the only message I get from `window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction` is "undefined" no matter what I do, even if I hard code the response, and the image is removed from the text editor.

I also can't get the `CKEditor` and `CKEditorFuncNum` variables in my php.

The js code is:

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'blog-text', {
    extraPlugins: 'uploadimage',
    // Upload images to a CKFinder connector
    uploadUrl: '/webhook/uploadimage?type=Files',
</script>
```

the php called is:

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $CKEditor = Input::get('CKEditor');
    $funcNum = Input::get('CKEditorFuncNum');

    $message = $url = 'freem';
    if (Input::hasFile('upload')) {
        $file = Input::file('upload');
        if ($file->isValid()) {
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            Storage::disk('s3')->put('/' . $filename , file_get_contents($file));
        }
    }
    $url = $filename;
    return response()->json('<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(2, "'.$url.'", "'.$message.'")</script>');
    }
```

I've looked everywhere online and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I can't even figure out how to get an error message that helps me debug.